# Sql timestamp for created/updated dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In a few logging tables that are frequently written to, I'd like to be able to store a relative order so that I can union between these tables, and get the order that things actually occurred in.

DateTime2's resolution is lacking. Several rows will get the exact same date, so there is no way to tell which happened first. 
Because sorting should work across several tables, sorting by Id is out.

Then I started looking at timestamp. This works for updated dates, but it does not work for created dates, because you can only have one timestamp column per table, and it automatically updates.

This is for Microsoft Sql Server 2008.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simulate it with another column typed as `binary(8)` (same as [`rowversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)) and defaulting to [`@@DBTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187366.aspx):

```
create table TX (
    ID int not null,
    Updated rowversion not null,
    Created binary(8) not null constraint DF_TX_Created DEFAULT (@@DBTS)
)
go
insert into TX (ID)
values (1),(2)
go
update TX set ID = 3 where ID = 1
go
insert into TX (ID)
values (4)
go
select * from TX
```

Result:

```
ID          Updated            Created
----------- ------------------ ------------------
3           0x00000000000007D3 0x00000000000007D0
2           0x00000000000007D2 0x00000000000007D0
4           0x00000000000007D4 0x00000000000007D3
```

Notes:

The `Created` values will always be equal to the last `rowversion` value assigned, so they will "lag", in some sense, compared to `Updated` values.

Also, multiple inserts from a single statement will receive the *same* `Created` values, whereas `Updated` values will always be distinct.

Comment: And, if the duplicate Created column values are a problem, you could have an INSERT trigger that set Created to match the initial Updated value.